# Terminal interface audio player based on VLC & Curses

Tags: python, audio, curses

I'm working on an audio player with a terminal interface. I'm designing it for eventual use on a Raspberry Pi with a 480x320px display.

I've broken the code into three main files with the intention of keeping the business logic (player.py) and graphics (view.py) separated and connected only through the main file. I've also included a configuration file where I'm storing future user options and text strings.

I have more functionality planned, so I'd like to make sure I have a solid foundation now while the complexity is low.

Any comments on the architecture, style, or efficacy of the code are welcome. The code is also available on on [github](https://github.com/ReticulatedSpline/openDAP).

**main.py**

```
import sys, os
from pynput import keyboard
from functools import partial

import cfg
from view import View
from player import Player

exit_signal: bool = False
def on_press(key: keyboard.KeyCode, view: View, player: Player):
    """Handle input"""
    global exit_signal
    key = str(key).strip('\'')
    if str(key) == 'p':
        view.notify('Playing...')
        player.play()
    elif key == 'a':
        view.notify('Paused')
        player.pause()
    elif key == 'n':
        view.notify('Skipping Forward...')
        player.skip_forward()
    elif key == 'l':
        view.notify('Skipping Back...')
        player.skip_back()
    elif key == 'q':
        view.notify('Exiting...')
        exit_signal = True
        del player
        del view
        return
    view.update_ui(player.get_metadata())

def tick(view: View, player:Player):
    """For functions run periodically"""
    metadata = player.get_metadata()
    view.update_ui(metadata)

view = View()
player = Player()

view.notify("Ready!")
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=partial(on_press, view=view, player=player)) as listener:
    while exit_signal == False:
        tick(view, player)
    listener.join() # merge to one thread
    os.system('reset') # clean up the console
```

**player.py**

```
import os
import vlc  # swiss army knife of media players
import cfg
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3 as ID3  # audio file metadata

music_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '../../music'))
playlist_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '../../playlists'))

class Player:
    """Track player state, wrap calls to the VLC plugin, and handle scanning for media."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.song_list = []
        self.song_idx = 0
        self.song_idx_max = 0
        self.vlc = vlc.Instance()
        self._scan_library()
        self.player = self.vlc.media_player_new(self.song_list[self.song_idx])
        self._update_song()

    def __del__(self):
        del self.vlc
        return

    def _scan_library(self):
        for dirpath, _, files in os.walk(music_path):
            for file in files:
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                _, ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
                if ext in cfg.file_types:
                    self.song_list.append(filepath)
                    self.song_idx_max += 1

    def _get_id3(self, key: str):
        metadata = ID3(self.song_list[self.song_idx])
        return str(metadata[key]).strip('[\']')

    def _update_song(self):
        if self.song_list and self.song_idx < len(self.song_list):
            self.media = self.vlc.media_new(self.song_list[self.song_idx])
            self.media.get_mrl()
            self.player.set_media(self.media)

    def get_metadata(self):
        """Return a dictionary of title, artist, current runtime and total runtime."""
        if (not self.song_list) or (self.song_idx < 0):
            return None
        else:
            # default states when not playing a track are negative integers
            curr_time = self.player.get_time() / 1000 # time returned in ms
            if (curr_time < 0):
                curr_time = 0
            run_time = self.player.get_length() / 1000
            if (run_time < 0):
                run_time = 0
                playing = False
            else:
                playing = True
            info = {"playing": playing,
                    "title": self._get_id3('title'),
                    "artist": self._get_id3('artist'),
                    "curr_time": curr_time,
                    "run_time": run_time}
            return info

    def play(self):
        """Start playing the current track."""
        self.player.play()

    def pause(self):
        """Pause the current track. Position is preserved."""
        self.player.pause()

    def skip_forward(self):
        """Skip the the beginning of the next track and start playing."""
        if (self.song_idx < self.song_idx_max):
            self.song_idx += 1
        self._update_song()
        self.play()

    def skip_back(self):
        """Skip to the beginning of the last track and start playing."""
        if (self.song_idx > 0):
            self.song_idx -= 1
        self._update_song()
        self.play()
```

**view.py**

```
import cfg  # settings
import curses  # textual user interface
from datetime import timedelta

class View:
    """Wrap the python Curses library and handle all aspects of the TUI."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = curses.initscr()
        self.max_y_chars, self.max_x_chars = self.screen.getmaxyx()

        self._draw_border()

        self.line1 = self.max_y_chars - 4
        self.line2 = self.max_y_chars - 3
        self.line3 = self.max_y_chars - 2
        self.screen.refresh()

    def __del__(self):
        """Restore the previous state of the terminal"""
        curses.endwin()

    def _draw_border(self):
        self.screen.border(0)
        self.screen.addstr(0, (self.max_x_chars - len(cfg.title)) // 2, cfg.title)

    def _set_cursor(self):
        self.screen.move(2, len(cfg.prompt_en) + 2)

    def _clear_line(self, line: int):
        self.screen.move(line, 1)
        self.screen.clrtoeol()
        self._draw_border()

    def _strfdelta(self, tdelta: timedelta):
        """Format a timedelta into a string"""
        days = tdelta.days
        hours, rem = divmod(tdelta.seconds, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)

        time_str = ''
        if days > 0:
            time_str += str(days) + ' days, '
        if hours > 0:
            time_str += str(hours) + ' hours '
        time_str += str(minutes)
        time_str += ':'
        if (seconds < 10):
            time_str += '0'
        time_str += str(seconds)
        return time_str

    def _update_progress_info(self, metadata):
        if metadata is None:
            return

        run_time = metadata["run_time"]
        curr_time = metadata["curr_time"]

        if run_time == 0:
            return

        percent = int((curr_time / run_time) * 100)
        run_time_str = self._strfdelta(timedelta(seconds=run_time))
        curr_time_str = self._strfdelta(timedelta(seconds=curr_time))
        time_str = curr_time_str + cfg.time_sep_en + run_time_str + ' (' + str(percent) + '%)'

        # two border characters
        progress_bar_chars = self.max_x_chars - 2
        fill_count = int(progress_bar_chars * curr_time / run_time)
        progress_fill = cfg.prog_fill * fill_count
        progress_void = ' ' * (progress_bar_chars - fill_count)
        progress_bar = progress_fill + progress_void

        self.screen.addstr(self.line2, 1, time_str)
        self.screen.addstr(self.line3, 1, progress_bar)

    def notify(self, string: str):
        """Add a string to the top of the window."""
        self._clear_line(1)
        self.screen.addstr(1, 1, string)
        self._set_cursor()
        self.screen.refresh()

    def update_ui(self, metadata: dict):
        """Update track metadata and progress indicators."""

        self._clear_line(self.line1)
        self._clear_line(self.line2)
        self._clear_line(self.line3)
        if metadata is None:
            return
        else:
            if metadata['playing']:
                info_line = metadata['title'] + cfg.song_sep_en + metadata['artist']
                self.screen.addstr(self.line1, 1, info_line)
            self.screen.addstr(2, 1, cfg.prompt_en)
            self._update_progress_info(metadata)
        self._draw_border()
        self._set_cursor()
        self.screen.refresh()
```

**cfg.py**

```
# text strings
title = 'OpenDAP v0.0.0.1'
no_media_en = "Nothing is playing!"
no_load_en = "..."
no_progress_en = "Cannot display progress."
prompt_en = "[P]lay, P[a]use, [N]ext, [L]ast, [Q]uit ▶ "
song_sep_en = " by "
time_sep_en = " of "

# file types to scan for
file_types = {'.mp3', '.flac'}

# progress bar filler
prog_fill = '▒'
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is pretty good.

- You have some Pythonic style problems like `on_press` should have two blank lines before it, mypy probably would complain about `exit_singal: bool = False` and un-Pythonic `if (...):` statements. And so I recommend that you run a linter or two on your code.
- Personally I don't like `view.notify('Playing...')` and then `player.play()`. Personally I would prefer if `view` and `player` had the same interface for signals. This would mean that you would have:

  ```py
  if key == 'p':
      view.play()
      player.play()
  ```
- Personally I would prefer `raise SystemExit(0)` rather than `exit_signal`. This reduces the size of the global scope. You should be able to achieve the same results with a `try` `finally`.
- If you utilize `SystemExit` and make `view` and `player` have the same interface. Then you could convert `on_press` to be super simple, by using a dictionary:

  ```py
  INTERFACE = {
      'p': 'play',
      'a': 'pause',
      'n': 'skip_forward',
      'l': 'skip_back',
      'q': 'quit',
  }

  def on_press(key: keyboard.KeyCode, view: View, player: Player):
      key = str(key).strip("'")
      function = INTERFACE.get(key, None)
      if function is not None:
          getattr(view, function)()
          getattr(player, function)()
      view.update_ui(player.get_metadata())
  ```
- I've found it to be very rare to need to use `del`, or ever define `__del__`. Maybe you *really* need it, maybe you don't?
- You can use `f'{minutes}:{seconds:0>2}'` so that the seconds are padded in `View._strfdelta`.

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of great improvements in this answer. Marking it as the solution for now.